# FtpGetFile not downloading updated file

Tags: c, ftp, wininet

I have written below code to download the file from FTP server in a specified,
the problem is whenever i modify the file in the FTP server the programming is not downloading the modified the file, its still downloading the old file,
i think its because of caching, i have googled but did not get the answer 
i using gcc compiler in windows with wininet.

```
using namespace std;
char USER_NAME[100]="test",
    PASSWORD[100]="test",
    HOST_NAME[100]="localhost";

int main()
{

    while(1){
            int t=0;
            int z=0;
         HINTERNET hint,hftp;
        z=DeleteFile("aaa.txt");
        cout<<"file status="<<z<<endl;
        Sleep(5000);
        hint = InternetOpen("FTP",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,0,0,INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
        hftp = InternetConnect(hint,"localhost",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);
        t=FtpGetFile(hftp,"/config/config.txt","aaa.txt",FALSE,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,0);
        printf("//t value=:%d\n",t);
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        Sleep(20000);
    }

}
```

[image: here is the screenshot of server log for my program]

[image: screenshot of server log for filezilla ftp client.]

i downloaded file thrice in both the cases.

Comment: What happens if you download the file using a regular FTP client? Does it download the updated version or the old (cached) version?

Comment: if i use ftp client it downloads the updated file. im testing this program by creating local ftp server(using filezilla).

Comment: It looks like you need either the `INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD` flag or the `INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE` flag. Just OR it with your `FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY` flag in your call to `FtpGetFile`.

Comment: tried all above solutions but still the same problem.

Comment: It looks like you have the _fFailIfExists_ and _dwFlagsAndAttributes_ parameters of `FtpGetFile` in the wrong order.

Comment: sorry, i didnt notce the mistake, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Show us FileZilla Server log for download using your code and using the regular FTP client.

Comment: i have updated the question,

Comment: Log files, not screenshots of log, please. Also the logs seems strange. Why are there two connections in the "my program" log? Are you sure both belong to the connection by your program?